# Azure Party Cluster: Unable to add certificate to Windows 7

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I registered for Azure Service Fabric Party Cluster. After registration it provided two keys: PFX and PEM .

The instructions given [here](https://try.servicefabric.azure.com/sfxhelp.html) says that while installing on Windows, if it asks for password, leave it empty and proceed.

But while installing it is asking for password. When leaving empty it is showing error: "Password entered is incorrect".

How to install it without password?

[image]

Comment: If you Configure the Service Fabric cluster the certificate from a certificate with a Password , you need to input password when when you import it. It depends what certificate that you used for the SF cluster.  Check the certificate source and find the password.